# EJB Reference Configuration Error

Tags: cluster-computing, websphere-6.1

I have 2 ears—say, Ear1 and Ear2—for my application, which are deployed in clusters. Ear2 is having Ejb which is being called from Ear1. EJB reference is required for communication between Ear2 and Ear1. I am setting the below value to 
Target Resource JNDI Name:  corbaloc::ClusterServer1:2810,:ClusterServer2:2810/cell/clusters/Cluster1/ejb/com/mycompanyName/projectName/ejb/facade/EjbFacadeHome

But I am getting the below error:

`Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: A communication failure occurred while attempting to obtain an initial context with the provider URL: "corbaloc::mums00100251.in.net.intra:2810,:mums00100392.in.net.intra:2810/cell/clusters/Cluster1/ejb/com/bnpparibas/tradefinance/ejb/facade/EjbFacadeHome".  Make sure that any bootstrap address information in the URL is correct and that the target name server is running.`

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The correct format for referencing remote EJB with WebSphere Application Server 6.1 in this case would be like:

> corbaloc:iiop:mums00100251.in.net.intra:2810/ejb/com/bnpparibas/tradefinance/ejb/facade/EjbFacadeHome,iiop:mums00100392.in.net.intra:2810/ejb/com/bnpparibas/tradefinance/ejb/facade/EjbFacadeHome

2810 suggests you attempted to use either the bootstrap port of node agents or deployment manager. I would check the ports (you can find the BOOTSTRAP port from the management console under Ports section of the server preferences), and if they still fail use the actual application servers' bootstrap ports.

There could also be a scoping issue which would mandate that. If you deployed your application to the Cluster scope it is possible that the naming service only in the cluster members can actually resolve the EJB.